# Redis caching - how to avoid race conditions?

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to cache DB queries using redis. For now pseudo code in single API endpoint looks like this:

```
GET /data
```

1. Check if object is in REDIS cache (by cacheKey)
2. If it is in cache just return it to client
3. If it is not in cache, then fetch data from DB
4. Write data to REDIS cache (at cacheKey)
5. Return data to client

I am caching objets that don't change often so I set expiration to 24h for example. The problem is when I want to update such object. The pseudo code looks like this:

```
PUT /data
```

1. Update data in DB
2. Write data to cache (or just set cache to null / delete form cache)

The problem is that after new data has been written to cache (or cache has been deleted) then still `GET /data` can overwrite new data in cache by old data. This happens when point 4 form `GET /data` is executed just after point 2 from `PUT /data`.

Is there any mechanism that will prevent overwriting new data with old data in cache?

Comment: Hmm that might be solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where the `PUT` puts the fresh data in the cache at the same time as it puts it in the database (write-through cache), you can use `SET` / `HSET` when writing to the cache from your `PUT`, and `SETNX` / `HSETNX` when writing to the cache from your `GET`. Since the `GET` is only going to write to the cache if the key doesn't exist, normally a `SETNX` will succeed. But if someone else (possibly a `PUT`) came along and set the key in the meantime, the `SETNX` will fail because the key already exists, and you'll get the result you want.

In the case where the `PUT` just deletes the data in cache to be repopulated by the next `GET`, I don't think you can provide any better guarantee than you already have. The data will live for one expiration time after it was retrieved from the database, which isn't strictly wrong, it's just worse than you would like.

Answer (score 5):

The NX approach as @hobbs had suggested still has a race condition. I'd add to it using WATCH/MULTI/EXEC blocks around your GET workflow for transactional-like behavior.

With NX-only approach, there's still a chance that between 3 and 4, a PUT will get in the way.

Comment: Hmm, I dont quite understand how WATCH works - it seems that it is not "bound" to transaction, but it is "bound" to redis connection? What will happend if there will be 10 GET requests and each one will WATCH same key?

Comment: No problem. It will just guarentee that the value you WATCH and GET from Redis didn't change until the EXEC. You are right in that the block is in the context of a single connection (like a tx in any db)

Comment: So it wont work - because there will be many WATCH/EXEC instructions executed in parallel. Because EXEC unwatches all keys that are watched it may unwatch keys that are watched by another transaction...

Comment: @ItamarHaber we *want* the PUT to win, so it's okay if it wins a race.

Comment: @user606521 no, the watches are only cleared for the connection doing the exec.

Comment: yes but that means that I would have to create separate connection to redis per each GET and this is not an option (consider 100 reqs/sec)

Comment: @user606521 no... two transactions on the same connection can't both be executing at the same time.

Comment: So when I will have one connection to REDIS and there will be multiple GET requests and each request handler will call WATCH + MULTI + EXEC then it will be OK?

Comment: I posted another question with sample code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258907/redis-multiple-watchmultiexec-on-single-connection

Comment: This won't work if you are simple invalidating the cache.